# AngularJS ng-bind-html does not appear to be updating the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is a basic example of what is happening. The HTML binding actually works just fine. I can even alert on $scope.testDocument and get my newly updated content. However, if I try and select any of the newly inserted HTML elements bound using the directive it always returns 0 length. Is there some relationship to the DOM I'm missing that jQuery needs?

**HTML Snippet**

```
<form>
    <button id="myButton" type="button" ng-click="testUpdate()">Test Update</button>
</form>

<div ng-bind-html="testDocument" id="testDocument"></div>
```

**JavaScript Snippet**

```
$scope.testDocument = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>My HTML.</div>");
$scope.testUpdate = function() {
    $scope.testDocument = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div><span class='test-new-element'>My HTML.</span></div>");
    alert($(".test-new-element").length);
}
```

**EDIT**

I wanted to add some extra details after dave's response below. After updating the bound element I added a $watch, which appears to be working and doing what I want:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return testDocument ;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue === oldValue) {
            alert($(".test-new-element").length); // Equals 1 as expected.
        }
    }
);
```

The documentation I read on this subject can be found at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope and by reading up on the $watch function.

Comment: IME if you're using data binding correctly, you pretty much never need to use jQuery to select elements.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but the usage is an edge case. The contents of the HTML are actually very large unlike the example. I am selecting/highlighting text, but some of the highlighted text is past the viewable area of the DIV, and so I need to scroll the DIV down to the position of the highlighted element. This is core jQuery functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to wait for the angular digest cycle to complete, until it does, the DOM has not been updated.  The simplest (although somewhat hacky) solution would be to wrap it in a `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() { alert($(".test-new-element").length); });
```

Comment: Thank @dave, this was it. Can you tell me if there is a digest listener that I can attach a callback to so I don't need a timeout? I can't seem to find much related to the digest cycle.

Comment: I added some details to the question that answers my comment above.